# how to drop rows from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `dataframe`

```
 name    cat1    cat2    cat3
 'aa bb'    A      A-1   A-1-1
 'cc dd'    B      B-1   B-1-1
 'ee aa'    C      C-1   C-1-1
 'gg bb'    D      D-1   D-1-1
```

and I have list look like this

```
list_words = ['aa', 'gg']
```

I want to drop all of the row's that **contains** `list_words`

**Update**

I have use this code but it's too slow, this code just for `aa`

```
dfg = dataframe.loc[dataframe.name.str.contains("aa", na=False)]
df_name = dfg.name.tolist()
for k in df_name:
    dataframe.drop(dataframe.loc[dataframe.name == k].index)
```

Comment: @S3DEV I added the code

Comment: Perhaps think of this the other way.  *Keep* only the rows which match a boolean mask, created by values in the column which are in the list.

Comment: @S3DEV I need the rest of the dataframe for rest of my process

Comment: `dataframe = dataframe.loc[(~dataframe.isin(list_words)).all(axis=1)]` This will do.

Comment: @DumbCoder tnx man, tnx

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df={'name':['aa bb', 'cc dd', 'ee aa', 'gg bb'], 'cat1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'cat2':['A-1', 'B-1', 'C-1', 'D-1'], 'cat3':['A-1-1', 'B-1-1', 'C-1-1', 'D-1-1']}
df= pd.DataFrame(df)
list_words =['aa', 'gg']

for i in range(len(df['name'])):
    if list_words[0] in name[i]:
        df= df.drop([i])
    elif list_words[1] in name[i]:
        df= df.drop([i])
```

Comment: Interesting approach, yet very inefficient.  A good rule of thumb, ‘if iterating a DataFrame, there is likely a more efficient solution’.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better answer:

```
df={'name':['aa bb', 'cc dd', 'ee aa', 'gg bb'], 'cat1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'cat2':['A-1', 'B-1', 'C-1', 'D-1'], 'cat3':['A-1-1', 'B-1-1', 'C-1-1', 'D-1-1']}
df= pd.DataFrame(df)
list_words =['aa', 'gg']

submask=df.name.str.split(expand=True)
mask=~submask.isin(list_words)

answer= df[mask[0] & mask[1]]
```